# Switching SubRoutes without unmounting MainRoute (React-Router-Dom)

Tags: reactjs, redux, routes, react-router, react-router-dom

**UPDATE (19 May 2019):** Removing `withRouter` from App did the trick. Now only subroutes unmount/mount as expected.

I would like to switch between subroutes without unmounting parent route. (i.e. going from /home/feed to /home/collections, should not unmount and remount the Home component (parent route); it should only unmount Feed compount and mount Collections component.

IN APP:

```
<Switch>
  <Route component={home(LandingPage)} path='/' exact />
  <Route component={index(Home)} path='/home' />
  <Route component={index(Browse)} path='/browse' />
  <Route component={index(Social)} path='/social' />
  <Route component={index(Notifications)} path='/notifications' />
  <Route component={index(Profile)} path='/profile/:id' />
  <Route component={index(SinglePost)} path='/status/:id' />
  <Route component={index(Settings)} path='/settings' />
  <Route component={NoMatch} />
</Switch>
```

IN HOME:

```
<Container>
  <Sidebar
    auth={auth}
    user={user}
    posts={posts}
    followers={followers}
    following={following}
    fetchFollowers={fetchFollowers}
    fetchFollowing={fetchFollowing}
  />
  <Wrapper>
    <Tabs>
      <Tab>
        <NavLink exact to='/home/feed'>
          Feed
        </NavLink>
      </Tab>
      <Tab>
        <NavLink to='/home/collections'>Collections</NavLink>
      </Tab>
      <Tab>
        <NavLink to='/home/locker'>Locker(α)</NavLink>
      </Tab>
    </Tabs>
    <TabWrapper>
      <Switch>
        <Route
          exact
          path={['/home', '/home/feed']}
          render={props => (
            <Feed
              {...props}
              auth={auth}
              user={user}
              searchTerm={searchTerm}
              populateNotification={populateNotifications}
            />
          )}
        />
        <Route
          path='/home/collections'
          render={props => (
            <Collections
              {...props}
              userId={auth.id}
              searchTerm={searchTerm}
              posts={posts}
              deletePost={deletePost}
              fetchPosts={fetchPosts}
            />
          )}
        />
        <Route
          path='/home/locker'
          render={props => (
            <Likes
              {...props}
              auth={auth}
              locker={locker}
              fetchUser={fetchUser}
              fetchLocker={fetchLocker}
              likedPosts={likedPosts}
            />
          )}
        />
      </Switch>
    </TabWrapper>
  </Wrapper>
  <Suggested
    auth={auth}
    suggested={suggested}
    fetchUser={fetchUser}
    fetchSuggested={fetchSuggested}
    fetchFollowing={fetchFollowing}
    followAUser={followAUser}
  />
</Container>
```

I expected App to remain mounted while navigating the subroutes (Feed/Collections), but App is unmounting and remounting when switching sub-routes. This causes components in App such as the Sidebar and Suggested to rerender even though they are outside the subroutes.

Answer (score 2):

replace `path='/home/collections'` in nested `Route` components with `` path={`${match.path}/collections`} ``

and also replace `to='/home/collections'` in links with `` to={`${match.url}/collections`} ``

see [this](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic) for example

Comment: Thank you for DRY tip. I've implemented your suggestions into my code base.